# Is the first has_many redundant? - Ruby on Rails Active records associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Rails 4.2 newbie:

2 Questions;

1) Is the first has_many redundant? Since its name is a plural of Save Class?

can I have only:

```
has_many   :savers, through: :saves, source: :saver
```

Or even better;

```
has_many   :savers, through: :saves
```

If the answer is yes, where can I set "dependent: :destroy"?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :saves, class_name: "Save", foreign_key: "saver_id", dependent: :destroy                        
  has_many   :savers, through: :saves, source: :saver
end

class Save < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :saver, class_name: "User"
  validates :saver_id, presence: true
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

2) This is the typical blog model, where user can 'save' posts posted by another user to their timeline. Does this model make use best practices? Specially in db performance, doing a Join to get posts saved by a User. The 'Save' table that will  have 100MM rows?

Comment: I love rails but 100MM rows will crush you, especially if you are new to rails.

Comment: The first question is a bit fuzzy but yes you do need to have `has_many   :saves` in order to have a `has_many :savers, through: :saves`. Since otherwise there is no relation between Post and Save.

Comment: As to if it matches best practices - thats hard to answer and a very opinionated question. However building an application of that scale in a framework you hardly know does not really sound like a good practice.

Comment: @max sorry for the fuzziness in first question. I need to change the column from saver_id to save_id in the Save table. This allow rails convention (class_id) and I can have just one line:  'has_many :savers through: :saves' I'm correct?

Answer (score 1):

Lets first alter your example a bit to make the naming less confusing:

```
class User
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :posts, through: :bookmarks
end

class Post
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :users, through: :bookmarks
end

class Bookmark
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Lets have a look at the query generated when we do `@user.posts`

```
irb(main):009:0> @user.posts
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "bookmarks" ON "posts"."id" = "bookmarks"."post_id" WHERE "bookmarks"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Now lets comment out `has_many :bookmarks` and reload:

```
class User
  # has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :posts, through: :bookmarks
end
```

---

```
irb(main):005:0> @user.posts
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the association :bookmarks in model User
```

**So no,** the first `has_many` is not redundant -  in fact its the very core of how `has_many through:` works. You setup a shortcut of sorts through another relation.

Note in `has_many :posts, through: :bookmarks` `:bookmarks` is the name relation we are joining through. Not the table which contains the joins.

To fix your original code you would need to do:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many   :saves, dependent: :destroy             
  has_many   :savers, through: :saves
end

class Save < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :saver, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :post # A join table with only one relation is pretty worthless.
  validates :saver_id, presence: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts 
  has_many :saves, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :posts, through: :saves
end
```

Note that you don't need half the junk - if you have `has_many :savers, through: :saves` ActiveRecord will look for the relation `saver` by itself. Also you only want to use `dependent: destroy` on the join model - not on the post relation as that would remove all the posts a user has "saved" - even those written by others!

Comment: On a side note, `Save` is a pretty confusing name as its more commonly used a as a verb than a noun unless your talking about sports. I would use `Favorite` or `Bookmark` or whatever.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you very much. BTW, the first I did was change the confusing name 'Save' :)

Answer (score 0):

Teaching Rails myself, I want to learn the professional way to use the framework and following Rails guidelines best practices. That's not easy, because I usually find answers that 'just works'

I'll try to answer myself and maybe it could be useful for Rails Newbies:

Using has_many through, association, Rails firstly infers the association by looking at the foreign key of the form `<class>_id` where `<class>` is the lowercase of the class name, in this example; 'save_id'.

So, if we have the column name 'save_id', we will have the following simplified model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user                      
  has_many   :saves, through: :saves
end

class Save < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :savers, class_name: "User"
  validates :save_id, presence: true
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

Comment: Post still needs `has_many :saves` for the association to work http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: @max I though that through: :saves in enough. And I can have:   "has_many   :what_ever_name, through: :saves" I'm correct?

Comment: No, you're wrong. I decided to reply in an answer instead of a comment.